# Intel Real Sense Audio Not Coming

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, intel, realsense

Am recording the video by intel real sense camera. The video recording is done and working successfully. But audio is not coming in that video.

For that my question is...

1. My configuration is Lenovo Yoga 15 with internal real sense camera
2. I want to install audio driver for sound ? Is that are required ?

please give me some suggestion.

```
session = PXCMSession.CreateInstance();
senseManager = session.CreateSenseManager();
senseManager.captureManager.SetFileName("new4.rssdk", true);
senseManager.EnableStream(PXCMCapture.StreamType.STREAM_TYPE_COLOR, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 30);
senseManager.Init();

for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
{
    if (senseManager.AcquireFrame(true).IsError()) break;

    PXCMCapture.Sample sample = senseManager.QuerySample();

    senseManager.ReleaseFrame();
    colorBitmap.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Do you some code to show??

Comment: I have added my code . can u pls give some comments

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the question well, so do you want to run audio and record the video together?

If yes, you have to create an instance of the class responsible for doing that.

take a look here [Speech Recognition](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/realsense/camera-sdk/v1.1/documentation/html/index.html?manuals_speech_recognition_procedure.html)

I used two threads in order to do that.  I have an application where I use facial recognition and audio recognition. I decided to split them and it worked very well.